# Intellij IDEA cannot open Local Terminal java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to start in linux

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

When I upgrade the Intellij-IDEA to latest version. I'm facing the issue to launch terminal in IDEA.

> 

```
 Cannot open Local Terminal
    Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, <-path-to-intellij->/ideaIC-2020.1.1/idea-IC-201.7223.91/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i] in <-path-to-project->
```

Below are the idea logs.

> 

```
 2021-04-12 17:05:29,428 [3739060]   INFO - .plugins.terminal.TerminalView - Activating Terminal tool window 
2021-04-12 17:05:29,451 [3739083]   INFO - erminal.AbstractTerminalRunner - Cannot open Local Terminal 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /<-path-to-intellij->/ideaIC-2020.1.1/idea-IC-201.7223.91/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i] in /<-path-to-project->
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:193)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.AbstractTerminalRunner.lambda$openSessionInDirectory$6(AbstractTerminalRunner.java:243)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown reason
    at com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess.execInPty(UnixPtyProcess.java:219)
    at com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess.<init>(UnixPtyProcess.java:59)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcessBuilder.start(PtyProcessBuilder.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:180)
    ... 13 more
```

Below I'm adding the Version details.

**IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Community Edition)**

**Build #IC-211.6693.111, built on April 6, 2021**

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265118. What Linux do you use?

Comment: I'm using the fedora 27

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217416

Comment: Thanks! Issue resolved when I restarted the Intellij-IDEA.